# How can i change hyperlink color with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I use a tag in ul li to make menu. now I need change color after click on link, but with below tag i can't changing this. please guide me

MY CODE:

```
$(".Bio").click(function(){
     $("nav ul li a").delay(200).animate({color:'#FFFFFF'},1500);
});
```

Comment: You cannot animate the color ( without plugin ). Use `$("nav ul li a").delay(200).css({color:'#FFFFFF'});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this:
http://jsfiddle.net/0nw60fdb/

```
$(".Bio").click(function(e){
     $(e.target).css('color','#FFFFFF');
     //change the css color of the target once clicked
});
```

Add this to the stylesheet (css)

```
.Bio {
    -webkit-transition: color 1.5s ease .2s;
    -moz-transition: color 1.5s ease .2s;
    -o-transition: color 1.5s ease .2s;
    transition: color 1.5s ease .2s;
}
```

Ease the transition of the property color over 1.5s with a 0.2s delay.